# w3 validator says all entities are invalid after final validation is corrected

Tags: html, validation, html-entities

I was going through corrections to get my pages to validate. I got it down to one error left on the page. After correcting that error, the next run of the validator gave 29 errors, one for each entity on the page. For example `&nbsp;` was now considered invalid. Here is one of the  error messages:

Line 67, column 12: Entity 'nbsp' not defined.

```
<h1>&nbsp;<a href="search-by-keyword.php?usertype=pri">M ...
```

In addition one other error was the following:

Line 1, column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

But this is the only declaration.

So as a test, I reverted the final error correction. After doing that, the validator once again says that there is only one validation error in the file.

As a side note, I did find an posting on the web from 2007 seeming to report the same situation. See http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2007Jul/0140.html

What's going on?

Comment: This'd be a lot easier to answer if we could see the code.

Comment: Validators frequently validate in a series of passes, and if it doesn't pass the first pass it won't start the second. Most likely your "single" error was the last in the first pass and when you resolved that it moved onto the second pass. To further help you we'd need to see your source.

Comment: XML? HTML? Which are you using?

Comment: You can see the page at dev.rephunter.net. htaccess credentials as follows: user: guest1, password: RH-dev=====guest1

Comment: Please just post a representative portion, preferably including the beginning, into your question.

Comment: Since you can now access the page, are you still wanting an extract?

Comment: I might have an answer, but at least the page now validates with no errors! I started searching around for info on doctypes, as I am not that familiar with the fine points, the current doctype having been selected by a programmer who is no longer on staff. I found on the page at http://www.validome.org/lang/en/errors/XML-DECLARATION , that if you had any leading spaces before the <?xml> line that it would be an error. After changing that so that there were no characters before the <?xml> line, our index page is now valid XHMTL 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to remove a leading space that got in from of the  tag, which is not allowed per the specification. In particular, the error message was exactly correct:

```
Line 1, column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

By "start of the document" is meant "1st character of the document", and no leading white-space is allowed.

This removed the above error as well as the 28 other errors.